# Build errors in MonoDevelop when building a custom widget

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm  extremely new to software development in general, and especially C#/MonoDevelop.  Please be patient.

While trying to build the holly-gtk-widget source, which has many many custom widgets, I get the following error:

c:\Users\Michael\Desktop\HollySource\HollyLibrary\RegExEntry\HRegExEntry.cs(9,9): Error CS0117: 'HollyLibrary.HRegExEntry' does not contain a definition for 'TextBox' (CS0117) (HollyLibrary)

here is the line of code:

this.TextBox.FocusInEvent  += new Gtk.FocusInEventHandler ( delegate { this.QueueDraw(); } );

The primary reason that I'm baffled by this, is because my custom widget container does in fact have a GtkEntry with the name TextBox.  As a matter of fact the MonoDevelop IDE will auto complete it for my while I'm typing.  I dont understand what is happening at all, I thought that TextBox may be a reserved name; but does not appear to be.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The TextBox field is exposed in the "designer" class definition which is located in:

HollyLibrary/gtk-gui/HollyLibrary.HRegExEntry.cs

That file is checked into the project, but the directory is hidden by default in MD.  You can expose it in the Solution browser via the DisplayOptions context menu.  It's possible there is a problem with the generation of that file if it is getting regenerated by MD during your build.  Check for errors/warnings in the build log related to stetic which is the Gtk designer in MD and take a look at that file.

If the designer partial class isn't generating correctly, you may be seeing a regression in MonoDevelop, or perhaps the HollyLibrary project files need to be updated.